# Can't access motion server

Tags: networking, camera, motion

I just installed motion but I can't get it to work. Im acessing my pi via local IP. SSH, VNC and apache works, but motion simply doesn't. I've already changed the ports at /etc/motion/motion.conf to lots of different numbers but none of them work.
I've found this command: sudo motion -n
When I run this, I get this message:
"Problem enabling stream server in port 7043: Address already in use"

I get this for every port I try.
Always when I configure a new port and run 
netstat -lnutp 
this port appears in the list and its marked as 'LISTEN'. I try to access but nothing happens. Does my camera need to work to motion at least appears when I try 192.168.1.x:7043? Can't I at least see the server running, even if the camera doesn't work? I'm using a microsoft USB camera, which appears to work with the rPi.

Here's the full list of errors:

```
[0] Motion thread 1 restart
[1] Thread 1 started
[1] cap.driver: "sonixj"
[1] cap.card: "USB camera"
[1] cap.bus_info: "usb-bcm2708_usb-1.3"
[1] cap.capabilities=0x85200001
[1] - VIDEO_CAPTURE
[1] - READWRITE
[1] - STREAMING
[1] Config palette index 8 (YU12) doesn't work.
[1] Supported palettes:
[1] 0: JPEG (JPEG)
[1] Selected palette JPEG
[1] Test palette JPEG (320x240)
[1] Error setting pixel format VIDIOC_S_FMT: Device or resource busy
[1] VIDIOC_TRY_FMT failed for format JPEG: Device or resource busy
[1] Unable to find a compatible palette format.
[1] ioctl (VIDIOCGCAP): Inappropriate ioctl for device
[1] Could not fetch initial image from camera
[1] Motion continues using width and height from config file(s)
[1] Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
[1] bind(): Address already in use
[1] Problem enabling stream server in port 7043: Address already in use
[1] Thread exiting
```

UPDATE:

Motion.conf file

http://pastebin.com/XF2aEJhD

Comment: it looks like you have a port conflict use this command netstat -tulpn to find out  what is listening on that port, and either close it or choose a different port for motion. You may also want to make sure you restart motion after changing the port.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I already tried lots of different ports, like 7043, which was not in use at netstat -tulpn. I've restarted too.

Comment: It's not clear whether your camera is working or not.  Perhaps motion will not create a web-page for a non-functioning camera.

Comment: @joan yeah, I think he would create too. I've tested a program that captures my webcam and it works. Also, now when motion is on, the webcam led ligths, so its working. The problem is that every port I choose, appears as 'already in use'.

Comment: Can you post the output of running `ps -ef | grep motion` ? To see if you have a other motion process already running.

Comment: @jotadepicas pi        3612  3368  0 15:10 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto motion
I've also restarted the pi several times, so its quite improbable that there's more than 1 motion running.

Comment: Thanks. Can you edit your question to include the full contents of your motion.conf file? (Mask any private information, if any).

Comment: @jotadepicas the only thing i changed was the port configuration. I tried to reinstall this package 2 times just to be sure the only change I did was at the port

Comment: Indeed I see nothing strange in your config... :( Could it be a permissions issue? Perhaps the process does not have sufficient permissions to bind the port and fails, but that is incorreclty logged as "address already in use"? (It's a longshot but anyway!) You could try running with sudo or as root, just to quickly check this (and if it works, correctly setup permissions so you don't run as root).

Comment: @jotadepicas I did sudo motion and the problem persists :(

Comment: :( is it a clean raspbian installation or do you have any other packages installed? Perhaps something else is interfering....

Answer (score 4):

You are wasting your time trying to get Motion to work reliably on the PI. Others have tried and it will disconnect from your cam after an hour or 2. This happened to me as well. Requests to the author of Motion to fix the bugs resulted in nothing

Comment: Ive been running motion for over 2 years now on ubuntu. When the new model 900mhz quad came out I figured Id try motion on one and it works great with arch arm.

Comment: It does seem to be something we get a lot of complaints about here.  Of course exceptions aren't the rule, but because people seldom post "So, all the software is working fine today," it's hard to tell what "the rule" actually amounts to -- I haven't used motion myself.  I do think the camera is more reliable at half resolution.

Answer (score 4):

Using motion V4.0 this helpful parameters are:

```
# change the following options in your motion.conf from on to off

stream_localhost off
stream_port 8081

webcontrol_localhost off
webcontrol_port 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not solve all your errors but will ensure that your options are set according to your expectation that the Motion server is not only reachable through `http://localhost:8080`

```
# change the following options in your motion.conf from on to off

webcam_localhost off
webcam_port 8081

control_localhost off
control_port 8080
```