# Can't access to motion from internet

Tags: web-server, bash, motion, lighttpd

I'm trying to make a server with motion , lighttpd and cgi scripting bash, everything is fine excepted from outside of my network (internet).
Those are my files and log.
Somebody can help me please?
I will really appreciate

---

> page web on server

[image]

---

> Ports in my router

[image]

---

> ports do not respond to requests

[image]

---

> netstat -tulpn

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante        Etat       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1026            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      - 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

---

> sudo motion -c motion.conf

```
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_load: Configfile motion.conf not found - trying defaults.: No such file or directory
[3958080] [NTC] [ALL] conf_load: Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "despeckle"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "gap"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "max_mpeg_time"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "output_all"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "output_normal"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "output_motion"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "ppm"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "ffmpeg_cap_new"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "ffmpeg_cap_motion"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "locate"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "jpeg_filename"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "webcam_port"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "webcam_quality"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "webcam_motion"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "webcam_maxrate"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "webcam_localhost"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "webcam_limit"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "control_port"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "control_localhost"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "control_html_output"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "sql_log_image"
[3958080] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "sql_log_mpeg"
[3958080] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Using default log level (NTC) (6)
[3958080] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Motion 3.2.12+git20140228 Started with SDL support
[3958080] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Logging to syslog
[3958080] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Using default log type (ALL)
[3958080] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Using log type (ALL) log level (NTC)
[3958080] [NTC] [ENC] ffmpeg_init: ffmpeg LIBAVCODEC_BUILD 3685476 LIBAVFORMAT_BUILD 3680357
[0] [NTC] [ALL] main: Thread 1 is from /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0] [NTC] [ALL] main: Thread 1 is device: /dev/video0 input 8
[0] [NTC] [ALL] main: Stream port 0
[0] [NTC] [ALL] main: Waiting for threads to finish, pid: 3920
[1] [NTC] [ALL] motion_init: Thread 1 started , motion detection Enabled
[1] [NTC] [VID] vid_v4lx_start: Using videodevice /dev/video0 and input 8
[1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_get_capability: 
------------------------
cap.driver: "uvcvideo"
cap.card: "USB2.0 PC CAMERA"
cap.bus_info: "usb-3f980000.usb-1.3"
cap.capabilities=0x84200001
------------------------
[1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_get_capability: - VIDEO_CAPTURE
[1] [NTC] [VID] v4l2_get_capability: - STREAMING
[1] [ERR] [VID] v4l2_select_input: Unable to query input 8. VIDIOC_ENUMINPUT, if you use a WEBCAM change input value in conf by -1: Invalid argument
[1] [NTC] [VID] vid_v4lx_start: Using V4L1
[1] [NTC] [ALL] image_ring_resize: Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
[1] [ERR] [ALL] motion_init: Error capturing first image
[1] [ERR] [ALL] motion_loop: Video device fatal error - Closing video device
[1] [NTC] [VID] vid_close: Closing video device /dev/video0
```

---

my motion.conf
https://pastebin.com/bjjepsm7

---

my index.html
https://pastebin.com/Ga5tbcn4

---

> lighttpd.conf

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_redirect",
#       "mod_rewrite",
)
server.document-root        = "/var/www"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 1026
index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
## Use ipv6 if available
#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
```

> motion.log

```
------------------------
cap.driver: "uvcvideo"
cap.card: "USB2.0 PC CAMERA"
cap.bus_info: "usb-3f980000.usb-1.3"
cap.capabilities=0x84200001
------------------------
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_get_capability: - VIDEO_CAPTURE
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_get_capability: - STREAMING
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_select_input: name = "Camera 1", type 0x00000002, status 00000000
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_select_input: - CAMERA
[1] [WRN] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_select_input: Device doesn't support VIDIOC_G_STD
[0] [NTC] [STR] [Apr 09 13:16:47] httpd_run: motion-httpd testing : IPV4 addr: 0.0.0.0 port: 80
[0] [ERR] [STR] [Apr 09 13:16:47] httpd_run: motion-httpd failed bind() interface 0.0.0.0 / port 80, retrying: Permission denied
[0] [ERR] [STR] [Apr 09 13:16:47] httpd_run: motion-httpd socket failed interface 0.0.0.0 / port 80, retrying: Permission denied
[0] [CRT] [STR] [Apr 09 13:16:47] httpd_run: motion-httpd ERROR bind() [interface 0.0.0.0 port 80]: Permission denied
[0] [NTC] [STR] [Apr 09 13:16:47] motion_web_control: motion-httpd thread exit
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_set_pix_format: Config palette index 17 (YU12) doesn't work.
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_set_pix_format: Supported palettes:
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_set_pix_format: (0) YUYV (YUYV 4:2:2)
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_set_pix_format: 0 - YUYV 4:2:2 (compressed : 0) (0x56595559)
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_set_pix_format Selected palette YUYV
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_do_set_pix_format: Testing palette YUYV (640x480)
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_do_set_pix_format: Using palette YUYV (640x480) bytesperlines 1280 sizeimage 614400 colorspace 00000000
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_scan_controls: found control 0x00980900, "Brightness", range 0,255 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_scan_controls:   "Brightness", default -8193, current 130
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_scan_controls: found control 0x00980901, "Contrast", range 0,255 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_scan_controls:   "Contrast", default 57343, current 130
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_scan_controls: found control 0x00980902, "Saturation", range 0,255 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_scan_controls:   "Saturation", default 57343, current 64
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_scan_controls: found control 0x00980903, "Hue", range -127,127 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_scan_controls:   "Hue", default -8193, current 0
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_scan_controls: found control 0x00980910, "Gamma", range 1,8 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_scan_controls:   "Gamma", default 57343, current 4
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] vid_v4lx_start: Using V4L2
[1] [NTC] [ALL] [Apr 09 13:16:47] image_ring_resize: Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:47] v4l2_set_control: setting control "Brightness" to 25 (ret 0 ) 
[1] [NTC] [STR] [Apr 09 13:16:48] http_bindsock: motion-stream testing : IPV4 addr: 0.0.0.0 port: 8081
[1] [NTC] [STR] [Apr 09 13:16:48] http_bindsock: motion-stream Bound : IPV4 addr: 0.0.0.0 port: 8081
[1] [NTC] [ALL] [Apr 09 13:16:48] motion_init: Started motion-stream server in port 8081 auth Disabled
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:48] v4l2_set_control: setting control "Brightness" to 45 (ret 0 ) 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:48] v4l2_set_control: setting control "Brightness" to 65 (ret 0 ) 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:48] v4l2_set_control: setting control "Brightness" to 81 (ret 0 ) 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:48] v4l2_set_control: setting control "Brightness" to 97 (ret 0 ) 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:48] v4l2_set_control: setting control "Brightness" to 110 (ret 0 ) 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:48] v4l2_set_control: setting control "Brightness" to 123 (ret 0 ) 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:48] v4l2_set_control: setting control "Brightness" to 133 (ret 0 ) 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:48] v4l2_set_control: setting control "Brightness" to 140 (ret 0 ) 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:48] v4l2_set_control: setting control "Brightness" to 145 (ret 0 ) 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:49] v4l2_set_control: setting control "Brightness" to 142 (ret 0 ) 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:49] v4l2_set_control: setting control "Brightness" to 139 (ret 0 ) 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:49] v4l2_set_control: setting control "Brightness" to 136 (ret 0 ) 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:49] v4l2_set_control: setting control "Brightness" to 133 (ret 0 ) 
[1] [NTC] [VID] [Apr 09 13:16:49] v4l2_set_control: setting control "Brightness" to 130 (ret 0 ) 
[1] [NTC] [EVT] [Apr 09 13:16:50] event_new_video FPS 15
[1] [NTC] [ALL] [Apr 09 13:16:50] motion_detected: Motion detected - starting event 1
```

Comment: Looks like to need to forward port 8081 to 192.168.1.6 on your router's web interface.

Comment: Hello John,Thank you for you answer ports are open in my router, I add a new pic

Comment: see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/71889/78211

Comment: Thank you Fabian, I have read this topic but there is not solution my port is open in /tmp/motion.log  [1] [NTC] [ALL] [Apr 09 13:16:48] motion_init: Started motion-stream server in port 8081 auth Disabled

Comment: your `/etc/motion/motion.conf` is missing the keys webcam_localhost and control_localhost, you have "only" webcontrol_localhost in it, see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/43296/78211 (no guarantee that this is the solution) (btw: only if you start your comment with @ and the username, the user will get a notification about your response)

Comment: @ Fabian Hello Fabian, Thank you for your answer, I did what you says and still have same problem, this is my new motion.conf: https://pastebin.com/hBj0XG2G, maybe you can send me a motion.conf file that it's work. Thank you again